# PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, validation

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_c98ef61810" on table "licences"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(7) is still referenced from table "licences".
```

I already have  `belongs_to :approved_by_admin, class_name: 'Admin', optional: true`

But STill gives me this error why ?

```
    add_reference :licences, :approved_by_admin, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
```

Comment: you edited your question and now my answer does not make sense anymore. we need to know again what you want to happen to licenses when a referenced user is deleted

Comment: @Ursus , I changes that `on_delete: :nullify` later. But right now this is  my actual achema. I wan the field approved_by_admin null when I delte the admin. I thought optiona:true would do that But Is still throwing the error. . I actually dont eant to change the schema and handle this by validation if possile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the user want to set to null the reference in licenses when a user is deleted, but does not want to touch the schema. I think a `dependent: :nullify` on the `has_many` association for admins (application level) might be the solution

```
# admin
has_many :dont_know_the_association, dependent: :nullify
```